# Laravel - php artisan config:cache - [ReflectionException] Class cache.store does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

After running the command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

It returns the content of the config file plus

```
 [ReflectionException] Class cache.store does not exist
```

And the internet page at my ip adress shows this

> ?php return [ /*
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Application Name
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | This value is the name of your application. This value is used
>   when the | framework needs to place the application's name in a
>   notification or | any other location as required by the application or
>   its packages. | */ 'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'), /*
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Application Environment
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | This value determines the "environment" your application is
>   currently | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure
>   various | services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env"
>   file. | */ 'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'), /*
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Application Debug Mode
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages
>   with | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within
>   your | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
>   | */ 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false), /*
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Application URL
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when
>   using | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root
>   of | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks. |
>   */ 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://159.203.5.249'), /* |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Application Timezone
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application,
>   which | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have
>   gone | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the
>   box. | */ 'timezone' => 'America/Toronto', /*
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Application Locale Configuration
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | The application locale determines the default locale that will be
>   used | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this
>   value | to any of the locales which will be supported by the
>   application. | */ 'locale' => 'en', /*
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Application Fallback Locale
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current
>   one | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any
>   of | the language folders that are provided through your application.
>   | */ 'fallback_locale' => 'en', /*
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Encryption Key
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be
>   set | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted
>   strings | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an
>   application! | */ 'key' => env('APP_KEY'), 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
>   /*
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Logging Configuration
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out
>   of | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
>   | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize. | |
>   Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog" | */ 'log'
>   => env('APP_LOG', 'single'), 'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'), /*
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Autoloaded Service Providers
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on
>   the | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services
>   to | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
>   | */ 'providers' => [ /* * Laravel Framework Service Providers... */
>   Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
>   Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class, /* * Package Service
>   Providers... */ /* * Application Service Providers... */
>   App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
>   App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class, //
>   App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
>   App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
>   App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class, ], /*
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Class Aliases
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | This array of class aliases will be registered when this
>   application | is started. However, feel free to register as many as
>   you wish as | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder
>   performance. | */ 'aliases' => [ 'App' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class, 'Artisan' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class, 'Auth' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class, 'Blade' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class, 'Broadcast' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class, 'Bus' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class, 'Cache' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class, 'Config' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class, 'Cookie' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class, 'Crypt' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class, 'DB' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class, 'Eloquent' =>
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class, 'Event' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class, 'File' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class, 'Gate' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class, 'Hash' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class, 'Lang' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class, 'Log' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class, 'Mail' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class, 'Notification' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class, 'Password' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class, 'Queue' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class, 'Redirect' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class, 'Redis' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class, 'Request' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class, 'Response' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class, 'Route' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class, 'Schema' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class, 'Session' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class, 'Storage' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class, 'URL' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class, 'Validator' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class, 'View' =>
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class, ], ];

I'm using putty to connect via ssh to my vps server.

Comment: Is the php open tag at the beginning of the file malformed? It seems like it should be <?php instead of ?php

Comment: Interresting idea, I has problems with nano and shortcut, sometimes right click copy, numpad doesnt write numbers and maybe I removed a <. I'll test it.

Comment: That was it, thanks... I'm not use to the putty console...

Comment: No problem :) I will post the question as an answer, so you can flag your question as answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Judging by the output it seems that your config file has an incorrect php opening tag (`<?php`).